# Get online status of stream of Twitch team members

Tags: twitch-api

I want to get a list of all online status (if it is streaming or not) of Twitch team members for a given team name.

**My current approach**

1. Get team from API (`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/team/<team name>`)
2. Get stream status for each team member (`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/<channel id>`)

**My problem with this**

First request is okay and works as expected. but I have to request each channel / streamer by it self and not in bulk - and the responded data is more than I really need.

**Question**

Is there any Twitch API endpoint that I can use, that takes several channel ids and response just a flat dict of channel Id and flag if the streamer is online?

Like:

```
{[
    { id: 123, online: false },
    { id: 456, online: true}
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

1. Get all of the members `_id`property
2. Build url like `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=123&user_id=456`
3. Loop over response
4. If a response's `user_id` matches an `_id` -> User is online

**Source**

[discuss.dev.twitch.tv](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/get-online-status-of-stream-of-twitch-team-members/20764)